# How to manage different repositories for different clients with the same project?

Tags: django, git, architecture

Good morning, I have to manage a Django project where each client has small customizations, both in terms of apps and API endpoints. I would like to avoid having to manage too many branches for each individual customer. Some potential solutions I've come up with are:

**First solution**

In the .env file, add a field indicating the client `CUSTOMER=customer1`

```py
#settings.py
#...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework_simplejwt",

]

customer = os.getenv("CUSTOMER")

if customer == "customer1":
    INSTALLED_APPS.append('custom_customer1')
```

**Second solution**

Use various branches according to the client, with the various merge coming from master/main

**develop** --> **master** --> **customer1_develop** --> **customer1_master**

Comment: I am not really following what you aim to achieve.

Comment: IMO solution 1 and similar are too dynamic and it would be difficult to maintain separation. It would be easy for code meant specifically for one customer to end up being used with another. Solution 2 is okay but why does each customer need to be a branch? Why not entirely separate repository for them?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat To avoid copy and paste between repositories

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I would like the main project to be the same for all, so that once something needs to be changed in all clients, but avoiding mixing changes that belong to clients, the custom changes precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to this problem is to set up your project as a [reusable app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/reusable-apps/) (or a set of reusable apps). For example you'll create apps called `myproject_component_a`, `myproject_component_b`, etc. then for each customer you'll create a separate Django project (potentially with its own git repository) that uses these apps.

In their settings you'll add your apps in like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "myproject_component_a.apps.MyprojectComponentAConfig",
    "myproject_component_b.apps.MyprojectComponentBConfig",
    ...,
]
```

To include the URLs you can do the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("a/", include("myproject_component_a.urls")),
    path("b/", include("myproject_component_b.urls"))
    ...,
]
```

Any communication needed between the core apps of your project and the custom apps can be done using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/signals/) so that your core apps don't need to be aware about customer specific apps.

Structuring your project this way would allow you to customize things for one customer without them affecting the other customer, for example a particular customer can decide to have URLs prefixed differently from what you might be doing for other customers, you can remove / disable certain parts of your project for them, add in custom apps, etc. all without affecting any other customer.

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be to store a list of apps to add to the `INSTALLED_APPS` to the `CUSTOMER` environment variable:

```
# settings.py

import ast

# …

customer = os.getenv('CUSTOMER', '[]')

INSTALLED_APPS += ast.literal_eval(customer)
```

then we thus store `['custom_customer1']` in the `CUSTOMER` environment variable.